# Global Variable usage in Rxjs / Reactive Programming / redux observable

Tags: javascript, redux, rxjs, reactive, redux-observable

**Assuming I am writing rxjs epic like the following:**

```
const epic = (action$) => {
   const id = nanoid(); # function that generate uuid

   return action$.pipe(
       switchMap(action => doApiCall(id)).pipe(
           map(response => response.data)
           map(response => addToast(id)),
           catchError(error => addErrorToast(id))
       )
   )
}
```

as this epic will chain up in epic middleware the uuid will not be generate every time a event emitted

how should make the nanoid event generate on event emit and pass it along to the response and error catching block

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure I understand the problem, but if you want a new values for id each time `action$` emits, you can do it like this:

```js
const epic = (action$) => {


  return action$.pipe(
        switchMap(action => {
            const id = nanoid(); // function that generate uuid
            return doApiCall(id).pipe(
                map(response => response.data),
                map(response => addToast(id)),
                catchError(error => addErrorToast(id))
            )
        })
    )
}
```

Comment: oh , that's actually simple and what I was looking for! felt like an idiot now haha. I will mark this as the accepted answer !